# How to get all records from one table and null with other table

Tags: mysql

Hi i have two tables event_service and appointment_feedback in which i have
two records in event_service table and one record in appointment_feedback
so i want matching record with event_service table and null record with
appointment_feedback.

Please follow my table structure

First table:**event_service**

```
....................................
evsr_id      evsr_ev_id   staff_id
....................................
  1           101             1
  2           101             2
```

Second table:**appoitment_feedback**

```
....................................
fd_id    fd_app_id      fd_comment  
....................................
 1        101             test
```

**I want this output:**

```
.................................................
evsr_id     evsr_ev_id     staff_id   fd_comment
.................................................
  1           101            1           test
  2           101            2           null
```

I have tried below query but it is not giving null value it is giving repeeated value of comment i.e. test but it has only one entry in appointment_feedback table so i want two record from event_service table
and one record from appointment_feedback table with corresponding to that
record.

```
SELECT appointment_feedback.`fd_id`,`fd_app_id`,`fd_comment`,`fd_service_rat` 
FROM event_service
left join `appointment_feedback`
    on event_service.evsr_ev_id=appointment_feedback.fd_app_id 
WHERE appointment_feedback.fd_app_id='3959'
```

This query is giving wrong Output:-

```
..............................................
fd_id   fd_app_id  fd_comment fd_service_rat
.............................................
  1       101        test           0
  1       101        test           0
```

Comment: it is simple left join

Comment: You should swap the select and the left join in your Query. `Select ... FROM event_service left join appointment_feedback ...`

Comment: Can you please post your answer.

Answer (score 1):

I have used simple LEFT JOIN it give requested output.

```
DECLARE @event_service AS Table
(
    evsr_id INT,
    evsr_ev_id INT,
    staff_id INT
)

DECLARE @appoitment_feedback AS Table
(
    fd_id INT,
    fd_app_id INT,
    fd_comment VARCHAR(50)
)

INSERT INTO @event_service VALUES(1,101,1)
INSERT INTO @event_service VALUES(2,101,2)

INSERT INTO @appoitment_feedback VALUES(1,101,'test')

SELECT
    es.*,
    af.fd_comment
FROM @event_service es
LEFT JOIN @appoitment_feedback af ON es.evsr_ev_id=af.fd_app_id
AND es.evsr_id=af.fd_id
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: no in my tables evsr_id is common for both the tables

Comment: I have update answer please check. Now you have to apply other condition with evsr_id column

Comment: i have tried but your query is also giving the wrong output i have posted the wrong output in my question

Answer (score 0):

According to your question, you had the right tools but you miss-used them.

This is your current query:

```
SELECT appointment_feedback.`fd_id`,`fd_app_id`,`fd_comment`,`fd_service_rat` FROM `appointment_feedback` left join event_service on event_service.evsr_ev_id=appointment_feedback.fd_app_id WHERE appointment_feedback.fd_app_id='3959'
```

All what you have to do is swap the tables in a way to select from `event_service` and left join `appointment_feedback`, so this should be your new query:

```
SELECT appointment_feedback.`fd_id`,`fd_app_id`,`fd_comment`,`fd_service_rat` 
FROM event_service
left join `appointment_feedback`
    on event_service.evsr_ev_id=appointment_feedback.fd_app_id 
WHERE appointment_feedback.fd_app_id='3959'
```

> LEFT JOIN performs a join starting with the first (left-most) table and then any matching second (right-most) table records.
>
> [image: Left Join Image]
>
> [Source](http://www.dofactory.com/sql/left-outer-join)

Comment: i have tried you query but it is also giving wrong output i have also edited my question with you query with wrong output hope it helps.

Comment: If it's not giving null values it means you have matching data.

Comment: i have two records in event_service table with evsr_id=3959 and one record with fd_app_id=3959.

Comment: Left join will match each row from first table to all rows in second table, therefor since you do have a row in the second table where fd_app_id = 3959 both rows from first table will match to this single row in the second table and you won't have null values.

Comment: i am not getting whats the issue is it possible to achieve the my required output or i am working in wrong direction.

Comment: Your issue I think is your table design. The query is returning the right result. What you should do is change the keys in your relations